# Android - Pusher - eventQueue Error

Tags: android, pusher

Why do I get that error? How do I pass information from this method/class to my other class? The pusher class/code fetches the data correctly and displays correctly however when I try to access other methods from another class it gives me the error below. Any ideas?
Here is my pusher code withn class Handler_Pusher:

```
privatechannel.bind("event", new PrivateChannelEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(final String channelName, final String eventName, final String data) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Private Test onEvent: " + channelName + "  " + eventName + "  " + data);
                docSyncData = getDocumentUrlExtension(data);
                final String URL = DOCUMENT_URL_PREFIX + docSyncData + ".pdf";
                Log.v(TAG, "URL:::" + URL);
                Activity_InCall.dialogLaunch(URL);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSubscriptionSucceeded(String channelName) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Private Channel onSubscriptionSucceeded: " + channelName);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationFailure(String message, Exception e) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Private Channel onAuthenticationFailure: " + message + ":::" + e);
            }
        });
```

Here's the method I'm trying to call within the class Activity_InCall:

```
public static void dialogLaunch(String data){
        Log.v(TAG, "Pusher:::" + data);
        Intent activityDocSync = new Intent(context, Activity_DocSync.class);
        context.startActivity(activityDocSync);
    }
```

Here's the logcat error that I'm seeing, the URL comes through ok but then gives me the "eventQueue" error which then goes into a null pointer exception:

```
11-23 09:58:12.551 19108-19771/com.talkative.reach V/InCallActivity: Pusher:::URL
11-23 09:58:12.598 19108-19771/com.talkative.reach E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pusher-java-client eventQueue
11-23 09:58:12.598 19108-19771/com.talkative.reach E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.talkative.reach, PID: 19108
11-23 09:58:12.598 19108-19771/com.talkative.reach E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
11-23 09:58:12.598 19108-19771/com.talkative.reach E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:77)
11-23 09:58:12.598 19108-19771/com.talkative.reach E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:4160)
11-23 09:58:12.598 19108-19771/com.talkative.reach E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.talkative.reach.Activity_InCall.dialogLaunch(Activity_InCall.java:398)
11-23 09:58:12.598 19108-19771/com.talkative.reach E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.talkative.reach.Handler_PusherPrivate$2.onEvent(Handler_PusherPrivate.java:90)
11-23 09:58:12.598 19108-19771/com.talkative.reach E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.pusher.client.channel.impl.ChannelImpl$1.run(ChannelImpl.java:100)
11-23 09:58:12.598 19108-19771/com.talkative.reach E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
11-23 09:58:12.598 19108-19771/com.talkative.reach E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
11-23 09:58:12.598 19108-19771/com.talkative.reach E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eventQueue` is the thread upon which the exception is taking place.

From the stacktrace it would appear the last piece of "user land" code is `com.talkative.reach.Activity_InCall.dialogLaunch(Activity_InCall.java:398)`.

A couple of questions I'd address would be:

1. Is `context` within `dialogLaunch` a statically accessible object?
2. Should this be accessed on the UI thread and not on the `eventQueue` library thread? See [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable))

Comment: That's why I posted the Activity_InCall.dialogLaunch part of code. I don't what's wrong with calling the intent like that.

Comment: Yea, I figured it out in the end. Thanks anyway! It wasn't anything to do with pusher, it was just me being silly and accessing non-static members from a static call etc etc. Fixed now

Comment: Not exactly. In the end I didn't actually use context (accessed in any sense). I left the access of dialogLaunch as static then used a messageHandler to access a fragmentDialog class (which I wanted to do in the first place). Also, I didn't access it via the runOnUiThread.

Comment: Same here, it was in my backend. Your comment pointed me out @hipkiss